# odoo 16 api required field "defualt Value" accept only numbers other values have errors

Tags: rest, odoo

..................model.py........
@api.onchange('field_id')
def _onchange_field_id(self):
self.required = self.field_id.required

```
@api.onchange('default_value')
def _onchange_default_value(self):
    if self.default_value:
        self.required = False

@api.onchange('required')
def _onchange_required(self):
    if self.default_value:
        self.required = False  




<group string="Settings for create/update" attrs="{'invisible': [('method', 'not in', ['post', 'put'])]}">
                    <field name="update_domain" widget="domain" options="{'model': 'model', 'in_dialog': True}"
                           attrs="{'invisible': [('method', 'not in', ['put'])]}"/>
                    <div colspan="2" class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert"
                         attrs="{'invisible': [('warning_required', '=', True)]}">
                   ..... Please note, some required fields have not been added to the list of fields, creating or updating may not work.......
                    </div>
                    <field name="api_field_ids"
                           context="{'default_path_id': active_id}">
                        <tree editable="bottom" decoration-muted="default_value">
                            <field name="model_id" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="path_id" invisible="1" />
                            <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                            <field name="field_id" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                            <field name="default_value"/>
                            <field name="force_required" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="required" attrs="{'readonly': [('default_value', 'not in', ['', False])]}"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>
                <group string="Settings for unlink"
                       attrs="{'invisible': [('method', 'not in', ['delete'])]}">
                    <field name="unlink_domain" widget="domain" options="{'model': 'model', 'in_dialog': True}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Settings for custom function"
                       attrs="{'invisible': [('method', 'not in', ['custom'])]}">
                    <field name="function_apply_on_record" attrs="{'required': [('method', '=', 'custom')]}"/>
                    <field name="function_domain" widget="domain" options="{'model': 'model', 'in_dialog': True}"
                           attrs="{'invisible': [('function_apply_on_record', '=', False)]}"/>
                    <field name="function" attrs="{'required': [('method', '=', 'custom')]}"/>
                    <field name="function_parameter_ids">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="path_id" invisible="1" />
                            <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="type"/>
                            <field name="description"/>
                            <field name="default_value"/>
                            <field name="required"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>
```

I was expecting the required values from UI and other values for char and text should be mixed or letters,numbers...etc but it only accept numbers. please help. Eg. when I use letters Error "description": "<class 'NameError'>: "name 'test' is not defined" while evaluating\n'test'"

Comment: ......... views

Comment: Can you share more information ??  because it can be due to field type or can  be logical error, given information is insufficient.

Comment: Dear Osama please find,  I added the views file above.